# Подскажите, как сделать чтобы при каждом цикле менялось значение переменной (хочу сделать "систему попыток")

Tags: python

недавно начал изучать Python и решил сегодня потренироваться, после того, как почитал пару книг. Поэтому, сразу говорю мои знания ***минимальные***. Хочу сделать, так сказать, систему попыток, но не могу додуматься каким образом сделать так, чтобы с X вычиталось 1 и при каждом цикле оставалось все меньше и меньше попыток.

```
capital = "London" 
running = True 
x = 4
while running:
    guess = input('Enter Capital of the Great Britain: ')
    att = 4
    if guess == capital:
        print('Congratulations!')
        running = False
    else:
        att = x-1
        print("No, you have yet", att, "attempts")


print('Game: Countries - END')
```

Answer (score 3):

Тут проще всего через цикл `for`:

```
capital = "London" 
for attempt in range(3, -1, -1):
    guess = input('Enter Capital of the Great Britain: ')
    if guess == capital:
        print('Congratulations!')
        break
    if attempt:
        print("No, you have yet", attempt, "attempts")
    else:
        print("No, and you have no more attempts, sorry")

print('Game: Countries - END')
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант через `while`:

```
attempts = 5
capital = "London"
while attempts > 0:
    guess = input('Enter Capital of the Great Britain: ')
    if guess == capital:
        print('Congratulations!')
        break
    
    attempts -= 1
    if attempts:
        print(f"No, you have yet {attempts} attempts")
    else:
        print("No, and you have no more attempts, sorry")

print('Game: Countries - END')
```

Или через `while True`:

```
attempts = 5
capital = "London"
while True:
    guess = input('Enter Capital of the Great Britain: ')
    if guess == capital:
        print('Congratulations!')
        break
    
    attempts -= 1
    if attempts <= 0:
        print("No, and you have no more attempts, sorry")
        break

    print(f"No, you have yet {attempts} attempts")

print('Game: Countries - END')
```

Answer (score 0):

или через рекурсию

```
def func(question, answer, failed_attempts=1):
    guess = input(question)
    if guess == answer:
        print('Congratulations!')
        return True
    elif failed_attempts:
        print(f"No, you have yet {failed_attempts} attempts")
        return func(question, answer, failed_attempts - 1)
    print("No, and you have no more attempts, sorry")

answer_results = [
    func('Enter Capital of the Great Britain: ', "London"),
    func('Enter Capital of the Great Russia: ', "Moscow"),
    func('Enter Capital of the Great USA: ', "Washington"),
]
print(f'Game: Countries - END. Правильных ответов: {answer_results.count(True)} из {len(answer_results)}')

# Enter Capital of the Great Britain: London
# Congratulations!
# Enter Capital of the Great Russia: 2
# No, you have yet 1 attempts
# Enter Capital of the Great Russia: 1
# No, and you have no more attempts, sorry
# Enter Capital of the Great USA: Washington
# Congratulations!
# Game: Countries - END. Правильных ответов: 2 из 3
```